# How to generate comments in hbm2java created POJO?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hbm2java

My current setup using hibernate uses the `hibernate.reveng.xml` file to generate the various `hbm.xml` files. Which are then turned into POJOs using `hbm2java`. We spent some time while designing our schema, to place some pretty decent descriptions on the Tables and there columns. I am able to pull these descriptions into the `hbm.xml` files when generating them using `hbm2jhbmxml`.

So I get something similar to this:

```
<class name="test.Person" table="PERSONS">
  <comment>The comment about the PERSONS table.</comment>
  <property name="firstName" type="string">
      <column name="FIRST_NAME" length="100" not-null="true">
          <comment>The first name of this person.</comment>
      </column>
  </property>
  <property name="middleInitial" type="string">
      <column name="MIDDLE_INITIAL" length="1">
          <comment>The middle initial of this person.</comment>
      </column>
  </property>
  <property name="lastName" type="string">
      <column name="LAST_NAME" length="100">
          <comment>The last name of this person.</comment>
      </column>
  </property>
</class>
```

**So how do I tell `hbm2java` to pull and place these comments in the created Java files?**

I have read over [this](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/codegen.html) about editing the freemarker templates to change the way code is generated. I under stand the concept, but it was not to detailed about what else you could do with it beyond there example of pre and post conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to add javadoc in generated POJOs is to use `meta` tags, like in this sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 2.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-2.0.dtd">

<class name="Person">
  <meta attribute="class-description">
  Javadoc for the Person class
  @author Frodo
  </meta>

  <id name="id" type="long">
    <meta attribute="scope-set">protected</meta>
    <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property name="name" type="string">
    <meta attribute="field-description">The name of the person</meta>
  </property>
</class>
```

So, to get something similar but including the comments of your tables and columns, my understanding of the [Javadoc Comments in POJOs](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2342064&sid=bb749324c5be6e4cbd44474c01e5cade) thread is that you'd have to modify the templates used to generate hbm files.

To do so, look at the freemarker templates of **hibernate-tools.jar**, `hbm/persistentclass.hbm.ftl`, `hbm/property.hbm.ftl`, etc (this is not an exhaustive list) and modify them.

For example, in `hbm/persistentclass.hbm.ftl`, instead of:

```
<#if clazz.table.comment?exists  && clazz.table.comment?trim?length!=0>
 <comment>${clazz.table.comment}</comment>
</#if>
```

I guess that you could do:

```
<#if clazz.table.comment?exists  && clazz.table.comment?trim?length!=0>
 <meta attribute="class-description">
  ${clazz.table.comment}
 </meta>
 <comment>${clazz.table.comment}</comment>
</#if>
```

And so on.

Comment: @Pascal That looks like what I am looking for. I'll come back and accept it once I am able to actually try it. Thanks for the help.